# How to listen keyboard in background and fire keystrokes on demand?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, keystroke, keyboard-hook, keystrokes

I want to make a program in vb.NET 2008 which will listen keyboard in background, i.e. even though the application is minimized (globally). If a specific key is been pressed by user, it should keep firing 2 other keys at regular given time intervals until the user presses that specific key again.

How can this be done in vb.NET 2008?

Comment: Yes it is possible.But why you want to do this.

Answer (score 16):

### Source : [Here](http://sim0n.wordpress.com/2009/03/28/vbnet-keyboard-hook-class/)

Usage:
To create the hook

```
Private WithEvents kbHook As New KeyboardHook
```

Then each event can be handled:

```
Private Sub kbHook_KeyDown(ByVal Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) Handles kbHook.KeyDown
    Debug.WriteLine(Key.ToString) 
End Sub 
Private Sub kbHook_KeyUp(ByVal Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) Handles kbHook.KeyUp 
    Debug.WriteLine(Key) 
End Sub
```

Keyboard Hook Class :

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class KeyboardHook

    <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Private Overloads Shared Function SetWindowsHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal HookProc As KBDLLHookProc, ByVal hInstance As IntPtr, ByVal wParam As Integer) As Integer
    End Function
    <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Private Overloads Shared Function CallNextHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function
    <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Private Overloads Shared Function UnhookWindowsHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
        Public vkCode As UInt32
        Public scanCode As UInt32
        Public flags As KBDLLHOOKSTRUCTFlags
        Public time As UInt32
        Public dwExtraInfo As UIntPtr
    End Structure

    <Flags()> _
    Private Enum KBDLLHOOKSTRUCTFlags As UInt32
        LLKHF_EXTENDED = &H1
        LLKHF_INJECTED = &H10
        LLKHF_ALTDOWN = &H20
        LLKHF_UP = &H80
    End Enum

    Public Shared Event KeyDown(ByVal Key As Keys)
    Public Shared Event KeyUp(ByVal Key As Keys)

    Private Const WH_KEYBOARD_LL As Integer = 13
    Private Const HC_ACTION As Integer = 0
    Private Const WM_KEYDOWN = &H100
    Private Const WM_KEYUP = &H101
    Private Const WM_SYSKEYDOWN = &H104
    Private Const WM_SYSKEYUP = &H105

    Private Delegate Function KBDLLHookProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer

    Private KBDLLHookProcDelegate As KBDLLHookProc = New KBDLLHookProc(AddressOf KeyboardProc)
    Private HHookID As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero

    Private Function KeyboardProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
        If (nCode = HC_ACTION) Then
            Dim struct As KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
            Select Case wParam
                Case WM_KEYDOWN, WM_SYSKEYDOWN
                    RaiseEvent KeyDown(CType(CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, struct.GetType()), KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT).vkCode, Keys))
                Case WM_KEYUP, WM_SYSKEYUP
                    RaiseEvent KeyUp(CType(CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, struct.GetType()), KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT).vkCode, Keys))
            End Select
        End If
        Return CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam)
    End Function

    Public Sub New()
        HHookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KBDLLHookProcDelegate, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetModules()(0)).ToInt32, 0)
        If HHookID = IntPtr.Zero Then
            Throw New Exception("Could not set keyboard hook")
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        If Not HHookID = IntPtr.Zero Then
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(HHookID)
        End If
        MyBase.Finalize()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I got Could not set keyboard hook error. whats wrong?

Comment: The code is working perfectly. But you have to 
Project -> [Project Name] Properties -> Debug -> Uncheck “Enable the Visual Studio hosting process”
As that intercepts the hooked messages before your program.

Comment: Hello, I am trying to execute a command with this code `Private Sub kbHook_KeyDown(ByVal Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) Handles kbHook.KeyDown
        Debug.WriteLine(Key.ToString)
        If Key.ToString() = "A" Then
            DF1Com1.Write("O:1/0", "1")
        End If
    End Sub`

However It does not work. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: i get the could not set keyboard hook exception, visual studio 2017, the option to disable hosting process does not exist

Answer (score 0):

If you use KeyboardHook class, make sure you have to build your program before using. With regards to the question for a specific key, you can trigger it in KeyDown or KeyUp event. But before that, you have to use sendkeys to send keys to active window.

> SendKeys.Send("L") 'Sends letter L to active window.

Then you can do the following code; below checks if letter "a" is being pressed.

```
Private Sub kbHook_KeyDown(ByVal Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) Handles kbHook.KeyDown
    Debug.WriteLine(Key.ToString) 
    if Key.ToString() = "a" then
     'trigger your sendkeys
    end if
End Sub
```

To trigger a specific key like a switch button, just declare a boolean variable to check if the button is switched or not. You can declare it globally:

> Dim switch as boolean = false

Just update the area where you set a condition to check the letter pressed. It will look like below:

```
if Key.ToString() = "a" then
  if switch = false then
    switch = true
    'trigger send keys
  else
    switch = false
    'deactivate send keys
  end if
end if
```

To have a specific time in sending keys, use timer. I hope it helps.