# Detect KeyUP in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to detect whenever a specific key is released, without focusing on the application.

I use GetAsyncKeyState, but it detects whenever the key is beeing pressed and not when it is released.

Comment: winforms? wpf? other?

Comment: Joel those just detect while the application is beeing focused, what if it is minimized?

Comment: Doesn't GetAsyncKeyState tell you if it is up or down?

Comment: @user3383786 I'm asking what kind of application you have. It matters a great deal to the answer, as it changes what api's are readily available.

Comment: Oh And WIndows form application, that's right.

Comment: @Rob It doesn't detect when it is released

Comment: You need to hook into the keyboard if you want to detect keystrokes (or releases) outside of your application having focus. See this post for how to do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038413/how-to-listen-keyboard-in-background-and-fire-keystrokes-on-demand

Comment: possible duplicate of [GetAsyncKeystate, check when KEY is RELEASED?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201231/getasynckeystate-check-when-key-is-released)

Comment: @user3383786 if it isn't down ... it's up.

Comment: Stop posting the same question over and over.

Answer (score 0):

```
If (GetAsyncKeyState(&H48) And &H8000) = 0 Then '0x48 is the "H" key which is up
    'your code
End If
```

for key codes [Virtual-Key Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

valter