# visual basic make key always assigned

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assign

I want to assign F keys always to my program 
I assigned F1 key to maximize my program
let say I open Firefox and my program minimized so when I press F1 key I want to maximize my program

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a `Global Keyboard Hook`.  Basically your program will ask the operating system to notify it whenever keys are pressed.  Support for this isn't built directly in to .net, but it can be accessed using p/invoke.

There is a very good example of it, along with VB.NET source code in this stack overflow question: [How to listen keyboard in background and fire keystrokes on demand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038413/how-to-listen-keyboard-in-background-and-fire-keystrokes-on-demand)