# Keyboard hook multiple key

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub kbHook_KeyDown(ByVal Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) Handles kbHook.KeyDown    
    If Keys.Control And Keys.Alt And Keys.Shift And Keys.N Then
        Me.Opacity = 100
        Me.ShowInTaskbar = True
        Me.ShowIcon = True
        MsgBox("CTRL + ALT + SPACE") ' This work
        Me.BackColor = Color.Indigo
        CheckBox3.Checked = False
    End If
End Sub
```

i use  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038413/how-to-listen-keyboard-in-background-and-fire-keystrokes-on-demand) I want the keyboard to listen to multiple keys when it's in the background, but this doesn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: Just to be sure, what is `kbHook` in this case?  Is that some kind of library you've added that installs an actual **keyboard hook**?  If so, can you link to the source or documentation?

Comment: Same thing goes for `Keys`...where did that come from?

Comment: It looks like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15038869/832052) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15038413/832052) is where you got your code. Its pretty well received so it should work. Did you make sure to `Project -> [Project Name] Properties -> Debug -> Uncheck “Enable the Visual Studio hosting process”` according to the comment?

Comment: yes djv   but " Enable the Visual Studio hosting process " was removed in Visual Studio 2017 (i use vb 2007) and i don't know how to make a program to wait until all key such as ctrl,shft,alt and h,  `If Keys.Control And Keys.Alt And Keys.Shift And Keys.N`  can't work , also `if e.contol .....` can't work

Comment: sorry @Idle_Mind  i edit question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Private Sub kbHook_KeyDown(Key As Keys) Handles kbHook.KeyDown
    If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown AndAlso
        My.Computer.Keyboard.AltKeyDown AndAlso
        My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown AndAlso
        Key = Keys.N Then

        Debug.Print("Ctl-Alt-Shift-N")

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: * * * * *  your awesome