# KeyDown With ComboBox

Tags: vb.net

[from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478730/keyboard-hook-multiple-key/56494878#56494878) i have the following items in combobox A,B,C,D,E,F,G i want keydown to check which item selected to combobox
i try

```
Private Sub kbHook_KeyDown(ByVal Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) Handles kbHook.KeyDown
 `If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown AndAlso
    My.Computer.Keyboard.AltKeyDown AndAlso
    My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown AndAlso
          ComboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString then ` 
'some stuff 
end if
end sub
```

in combobox i choose A(ctrl+alt+shft+A) but i got null error

Comment: This looks more like VB.net than VBA... can you clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: You should use a ComboBox event like `SelectedIndexChanged` and then check for `comboBox1.SelectedItem`.

Comment: Try with Combobox1.Text

Comment: `Combobox1.Text` can't work

Comment: @hans passant i need to make option user can choose it's keyboard key if i use `key=keys.N` it's work

Comment: @olivier please specify

Comment: The `KeyDown` event is not the right one when you are working with a ComboBox. See: [VB.Net - ComboBox Control (tutorialspoint)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_combobox.htm).

Comment: if combobox is not right please help with textbox

Comment: ComboBox is right; however, do not check for the selected item in KeyDown, but in SelectedIndexChanged. And there, check for the SelectedItem property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kbHook_KeyDown`  used when program run in background i think you want to show your form   i hope this will help

```
Private Sub kbHook_KeyDown(ByVal Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) Handles kbHook.KeyDown
    Select Case CStr(ComboBox2.SelectedItem)
        Case "A"
            If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown AndAlso
    My.Computer.Keyboard.AltKeyDown AndAlso
    My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown AndAlso
    Key = Keys.A Then
              form1.show
                Me.BackColor = Color.Indigo

            End If
        Case "B"
            If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown AndAlso
    My.Computer.Keyboard.AltKeyDown AndAlso
    My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown AndAlso
    Key = Keys.B Then
            form1.show
                Me.BackColor = Color.Indigo

            End If
        Case "C"
            If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown AndAlso
    My.Computer.Keyboard.AltKeyDown AndAlso
    My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown AndAlso
    Key = Keys.C Then
                form1.show
                Me.BackColor = Color.Indigo

                 Case Else
                Me.Hide()

End Select
            End If
```

Answer (score 0):

To check the selected item from a `ComboBox` do not handle the `KeyDown` event but the `SelectedIndexChanged` event. The `SelectedItem` property contains the selected item.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Select Case CStr(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
        Case "A"
            MessageBox.Show("First case")
        Case "B"
            MessageBox.Show("Second case")
        Case "C"
            MessageBox.Show("etc.")
        Case "D"
        Case "E"
        Case "F"
        Case "G"
        Case Else
    End Select
End Sub
```